# List not soowing data perfectly from database

Tags: android, list

I am new to android. I want to show inserted data from database to a table. I have used List to get the data.

```
 public List<user> getAllUsers() {
    List<user> users = new ArrayList<user>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(SqlLiteHelper.TABLE_USER, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
      user varUser = cursorToUser(cursor);

      //Log.v("user name",varUser.getName().toString());

      users.add(varUser);
      cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    //Log.v("user name",users.get(0).getName().toString());

    cursor.close();
    return users;
  }



   private user cursorToUser(Cursor cursor) {
    user varUser = new user();

    //Log.v("user id", cursor.getString(1).toString());

    varUser.setID(cursor.getLong(0));
    varUser.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    varUser.setPhone(cursor.getString(2));
    varUser.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
    return varUser;
}
```

I wrote this code on UserDataSource.java

Then where i need to show those data i use the following codes

```
       databaseSource = new UserDataSource(this);
    databaseSource.open();

    List<user> values = databaseSource.getAllUsers();
    Log.v("information", values.get(0).getName().toString());
    ArrayAdapter<user> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<user>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This is not adding the values in the list. I use the log.v to check whether the data is coming back or not. And i found that the data is coming perfectly from the database. Only when i try to print the List or insert it to the simple_list_item_1 then it is doing the problem.

It is printing

com.example.given_n_take.user@41221338

Buts its suppose to print the name from the database.

Database table name is user.

Please let me know what am i missing.

here is my xml file of layout where i am trying to add those list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/all_user_back"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Back" />



    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="384dp" >
</ListView>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what this cursorToUser(cursor); method do ?

Comment: The function corsorToUser(Cursor  cursor) is used to create a object of user class with the retrieving data. I am saving the list of object to LIST

Comment: We need to see your user class and the cursorToUser() method. The only thing i can think of is that somehow you map the wrong column to getName().. Please update

Comment: I have added the functions code to my question. Btw i got the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list shows `com.example.given_n_take.user@41221338` this means that you are missing a `toString` method in your `user` class. Implement a `toString` that returns the name of the user.

Comment: One more thing i just dont understand. Why my question become -1. I mean did i miss something on the question?

Comment: I cannot answer that, to me the question looks ok.

Comment: Now i can't even ask a question. :s anyway bro thanks a lot for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your ArrayAdapter calls the toString() method of your user object. You either have to implement to toString() method or if you want to show more than a string in your list, you have to write your own Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting wrong result because

```
Log.v("information", values.get(0).getName().toString());
```

`values.get(0)` will return class User consist of values like name ,id, phone no etc and to acces name you are calling getName method which is perfect. But for adapter you are passing `List<user> values` directly. So when adapter extract data out of it it will extract class User out of it not the different values. SO to access values you have to get the positioned value of list, extract values name, id etc and then pass it to adapter